# AngularJS edit JSON array by reference

Tags: angularjs

I am giving AngularJS a bash and am trying a small test app where I have a list on the left and based on what is selected, update a form on the right to allow editing of parameters. This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="tstApp" ng-controller="tstCtrl">

<div>
    <select size="2" style="width: 100px"
        ng-model="selected"
        ng-options="i as i.name for i in items track by i.name"
    />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="descr" value="{{selected.descr}}"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="ref" value="{{selected.ref}}"/><br/>
</div>

<script src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the JavaScript

```
var tstapp = angular.module('tstApp', [])
tstapp.controller('tstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
                {
                        "name" : "ITEM1",
                        "descr" : "This is item1",
                        "ref" : "Reference1"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "ITEM2",
                        "descr" : "This is item2",
                        "ref" : "Reference2"
                }
    ];
    $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
});
```

The problem with this is that when you actually change the description in the edit field, it remains like that and don't reflect the value of the array item any-more. I think the reason is probably obvious in that 'selected' is a copy of the array item and not the item it self. I can't seem to figure out how to edit the array item directly though that is currently selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind it as ng-model in order to get changes

Like this

```
 <input type="text" name="descr" ng-model="selected.descr"/>
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wpoe3gj/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I can see your suggestion works. I've changed the test on my host according to your suggestion and it does react differently but it does not remember my change to description i.e. changing selection in the list box just brings back the original value. When I try it in the fiddle it works though. I'm sure all is exactly as in the fiddle so I'm stumped.

Comment: As a follow-up. I think my problem is due to a bug in 1.4.8. When I change to 1.2.1 as in the Fiddle, it works :-(